# java Date object is always one day less

Tags: javascript, java, rest, date

I have user date picker where a user selects the date and it then makes an AJAX call to a rest service implemented in Java. But the issue is it always returns one-day previous date object. Here is my implementation:

```
testDate = $("#date-select").val();
console.log(testDate)
```

Above console.log prints the correct date. `2018-04-22`
But when it gets passed to rest service, it shows the wrong date:

```
@POST
@Path("checkDate/{testDate}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response demoService(final DemoBean demoBean)
{
    System.out.println("Rest service got called:"+ demoBean.getDate());
    if(demoDateConfService.setDate(demoBean.getDate())
    {
        return Response.ok(new Result(true)).cacheControl(NO_CACHE).build();
    }
    return Response.ok(new Result(false)).cacheControl(NO_CACHE).build();
}
```

This is the result of the Rest Call:

```
Rest service got called:Sat Apr 21 20:00:00 EDT 2018
```

Not sure if it has anything to do with timezone. My laptop is running in EST timezone.

Comment: Apr 21 8pm EDT == Apr 22 midnight GMT, print your date in GMT timezone and you will get Apr 22 00:00:00

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java.util.Date` is the most confusing class in Java Core.
I would not recommend to pass dates using `java.util.Date`, as it is intended to store both date and time.

As I pointed out in comments Apr 21 8pm EDT == Apr 22 midnight GMT. Print your date in GMT timezone and you will get Apr 22 00:00:00:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("Rest service got called:"+ sdf.format(demoBean.getDate()));
```

But I would rather recommend to send date as string or use `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the timezone to GMT making it to work just fine.

Comment: Thank  you. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` on ***SimpleDateFormat*** object did the trick.